# AJAX load structure

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to load a content without to reload the page, know i'm asking how the structure must work.

For example i have 3 links: LINK1 | LINK2 | LINK3

Now i have in the index the header and i want to load the content based on LINK1, so on default it must show homepage.

I want this to prevent reloading and so I am not obliged to copy the header to all files.

So what i actually want is something like this;

`// Here the header

Header Header Header

// Here the content 
include('based on link.');`

Now i know how to do this request with `$.AJAX` what i'm asking is how to does this work (the best way to do this).

I hope i could explain what i want and hope someone can explain how to work this out.

Comment: you just call your page url from ajax, get its html & then put into any container

Comment: best way to do what exactly? You really haven't been specific enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a index file with standard index file inside a div like

`<div id=content>Default index...</div>`

than make a `$.ajax();` call, load the data inside `$('#content').html(data);`